# Why does Python not cache integer values outside the range [-5, 256]?

Tags: python

I was experimenting with variable initialization in Python and I came across a scenario where the id(integers) in a certain range would be the same and the id(integers) greater than 256, Python creates a new reference.

Ex:

```
>>>> a = 2
>>>> b = 2
>>>> id(a) == id(b)
True

>>>> a = 257
>>>> b = 257
>>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

Reading through the documentation, it is clear that Python caches small integer values during initialization.

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/longobject.c#l5343

Why does Python internally cache only integer values in the range [-5, 257) During initialization?

Also, python shares references with strings without spaces and special characters.

So, I had a few questions:

- Why are small integers in the range -5 to 256?
- Why does it start with negative 5 and end at 256? It's a relatively small range. It would be more efficient if Python caches a bigger range. Wouldn't it?
- How is Python able to share references with really long string values but not integer values outside [-5, 257)?

Ex:

```
>>> a = "csjhdfsdkbvfbvkfdbkfdbkfjdbvfdbjhdvkdbvkdbfsgvxcxc"
>>> b = "csjhdfsdkbvfbvkfdbkfdbkfjdbvfdbjhdvkdbvkdbfsgvxcxc"
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True


>>> a = "csjhdfsdkbvfbvkfdbkfdbkfjdbvfdbjhdvkdbvkdb@"
>>> b = "csjhdfsdkbvfbvkfdbkfdbkfjdbvfdbjhdvkdbvkdb@"
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

Comment: It's an implementation detail of CPython, not a language guarantee. As for why that particular range is cached, it was deemed values outside that range weren't used often enough to justify the overhead of maintaining a larger cache.

Comment: *“How is Python able to share references with really long string values but not integer values outside [-5, 257)?”* That one isn’t an example of int-style caching; it’s about literals/some constant expressions. Try the same thing with integer literals outside [-5, 257) – it’ll work just like it does with strings – then compare `a = 2; b = 2; a + b is 4` with `a = "2"; b = "2"; a + b is "22"`.

Comment: *It would be more efficient if Python caches a bigger range* - how? If you deem a few -5 to -1 to be used for common error codes, 0-255 is a single byte each... how large should it go? And Python used to have a function called `intern` that enabled one to cache common strings... Python will however, cache strings that would be valid object names, so that's why your first string example works and the second one doesn't...