# How is memory handled in Python's Lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, memory, hashable

See the code below, as you see when **a=[1,2]** that is a homogeneous type the address of **1st** and **2nd** elements differed by **32** bits
but in second case when **a=[1,'a',3]**,there is no relation between address of **1st** and **2nd** element but there is relation between **1st** and **3rd** element that is address differs by **64** bits.
So I want to know how is **memory** handled and how indexing takes place and how is it linked to being **non hashable** (that is mutable)

```py
>>> a=[1,2]
>>> print(id(a[0]))
4318513456
>>> print(id(a[1]))
4318513488
>>> a=[1,'a',3]
>>> print(id(a[0]))
4318513456
>>> print(id(a[1]))
4319642992
>>> print(id(a[2]))
4318513520
>>>
```

Comment: FYI - you forgot to include the 'code below'

Comment: Use code blocks to include code, not images.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `id`s don't matter. Don't worry about `id`s. Don't look at `id`s. In fact, it's a [CPython implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#id) that `id`s are memory addresses, because it's convenient. Another Python implementation might do something else.

In any case, you're seeing CPython's small integer cache (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464966/why-does-python-not-cache-integer-values-outside-the-range-5-256)), where certain integer objects are preallocated as "singleton" objects since they're expected to be used often. However, that *too* is an implementation detail.

The string `'a'`, on the other hand, is not cached (it might have been [interned](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html#sys.intern) if your code had been loaded from a .py file on disk), so it's allocated from somewhere else.

As for your question about indexing, CPython (again, another implementation might do things differently) lists are, under the hood, arrays of pointers to PyObjects, so it's just an O(1) operation.