# Python variables behave differently after the value 256

Tags: python, variables, integer

In Python 3.8.10

```
pit@pit-desktop:~$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x1 = 256
>>> x2 = 256
>>> print(f'id(x1) = {id(x1)}, id(x2) = {id(x2)}')
id(x1) = 9809408, id(x2) = 9809408
>>> print(f'x1 is x2 = {x1 is x2}')
x1 is x2 = True
>>> 
>>> y1 = 257
>>> y2 = 257
>>> print(f'id(y1) = {id(y1)}, id(y2) = {id(y2)}')
id(y1) = 140250419837264, id(y2) = 140250419837488
>>> print(f'y1 is y2 = {y1 is y2}')
y1 is y2 = False
>>>
```

But in Python 3.6 at https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html
[image from pythontutor.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GiKc.png)

The behavior is radically different. What is it for?

Comment: If your program ever relies on int IDs, or the behavior of `is` on equal ints, you're doing things wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464966/why-does-python-not-cache-integer-values-outside-the-range-5-256

Comment: You run only one block (aka compilation unit) on Python tutor but several in the repl (each >>> is a new block).

Answer (score -1):

The IDs remain the same only as long as the specific object in memory referenced remains the same. With smaller numbers (less than 257?), it's more likely that they'll remain the cache. Try the same game using the number 42506, and you'll get the same False result as with 257, whereas when I did it with the number 32, the result was True.